# How to find the average intensity of a value that is proportional/inversely proportional to a value that changes by it's square/square root?

Tags: forces

When I've got a case where say, some car has a constant acceleration, I can calculate the average speed it had within a time interval by finding the arithmetic mean of the speed at starting point A and end point B.

But when I have a force, velocity or anything that depends on a value that is squared or is under a square root, how do I calculate the average intensity of such a value?

Comment: The average value $\overline{y}$ of a function $f(x)$ over an interval $[a,b]$ is given by $\large{\overline{y}= \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b  f(x)dx}$

Comment: Sadly, a calculus answer isn't helpful to me, is there some way you can say that without using it?

Comment: I can give an example. Say velocity is a function of time in seconds e.g. $v(t) = t^2$, then to find the average velocity between 0 and 5 seconds add together the velocity at 0 seconds, 1 second, 2 seconds, 3 seconds, 4 seconds, and 5 seconds and divide by 6. You would get an even better answer if you did the calculation using half-second steps. The integral computes the best answer (uses steps of infinite thinness).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed. So there's no way to just straight calculate it without calculus.

Comment: If you have a list of numbers {3, 6, 7, 10} you can compute the average (6.5) with algebra. If you have a function, you have an infinite number of points that you have to average, which is why you need calculus. For a linear function, it just happens that the calculus answer gives you the same thing as averaging the two endpoints, but that does not hold true for non-linear functions in general.

Comment: I see. Are there other functions which converge to a simple calculation?

Comment: yeah just average evenly spaced values of the function over the range of interest. decrease the spacing between values and that'll converge to the true answer